# Should I avoid special characters for table names in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to create a SQL Server database that will hold thousands of tables who's names will reflect  stock ticker names. For example, '0099-OL.HK' is a company's ticker name. Many of the stocks I'm creating tables for have special characters in them just like that.

I've read that special characters in table names should be avoided, but I still don't know why. SQL Server lets you use special characters in table names if you enclose the name with brackets, e.g., 'CREATE TABLE [0099-OL.HK] ...'.

Should I use the ticker names as their table names, or should I avoid using their special characters?

Comment: Your data model sounds bad in the first sentence.  Not thousands of tables.  Millions of rows.  That is how databases are designed.  Not one table per stock symbol, one table for all stock symbols.

Comment: It is definitely a huge red flag when you are putting information in the name of the table.

Comment: Please, no. Future Alex will thank you.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Well, every stock is getting updated every minute, so every record would be a minute. Would you still recommend to put every stock in one table, or should each stock be put on the same table?

Comment: @AlexMancheno . . . I think a watch could do one update per minute without problems.  Think hundreds or thousands of updates *per second* as a load that databases can usually handle.

Answer (score 1):

This will lead to no end of problems. The reason SQL Server allows names with spaces and special characters is because people migrate from databases that allow these characters in their names. If you must do this replace all special characters with _ like so: TN0099_OL_HK (TN for ticker name) so users can type sql without using the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

It is bad practice to do so, since not every library might be able to process the table name correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using special characters, spaces, and leading numbers in database names, table names, and column names.

For the full Rules for Regular Identifiers: [Database Identifiers - docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers)